# Grails no respecta sequencia

Tags: postgresql, grails

en mi base de datos tengo lo siguiente:

```
id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('seq_telefonosnormalizados'::regclass),
```

Mientras que en grails tengo lo siguiente:

```
static mapping = {
        id column:"id", sqlType:"long", generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'seq_telefonosnormalizados']
        version false
    }
```

Estoy usando Grails 2.5.1.

Alguno sabe por que no estaría funcionando?

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Mejor te cuento de mi experiencia...

MySQL genera por defecto las secuencias, así cuando recibe un nuevo orden de registro de datos incrementa a la siguiente posición... y, no es por orden de **grails** ya que éste solo se encarga de enlazarlas y de reestructurar el árbol de la **BD** según la configuración programada en el dominio.

Por ejemplo:
Necesito manipular los eventos que un administador realiza en un sistema X; la ***importancia de mi planteamiento*** es que solo debe existir un administrador en esa tabla llamada **admin** por ejemplo. Entonces no habrá nuevos registros sino quizás la modificación de los datos de ése admin y, para que no se permita nuevos registros yo preferí programarla desde el controlador **admin** para asegurarme de que nadie por maldad incluya un admin distinto e ingrese a mi control.

[image: control al crear mi admin]

Comment: el código debe ir como texto, no como imagen

Comment: lo siento, solo quise complementar mi muy breve explicación, ya que el código completo abarcaría mucho y bueno en realidad una serie de contenido de código.

Comment: si el código completo es extenso, entonces colocar un fragmento de el, no es de utilidad por que no ayuda a comprender el problema y solución en su contexto

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo solucione creando una secuencia en postgresql, y diciendole a grails y a la tabla que deben seguir esa secuencia!